# How to constantly check if mouse leftclick is being held down in mouseeEvent

Tags: java

```
static boolean enabled = false; 
@Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        enabled = true;
        if (e.getButton() == 1) {
            try {
                    do  {
                        
                        while (enabled) {
                            System.out.println("registered click");
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                         
                        }
                    } while (e.isMetaDown());
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "not working");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("released");
        enabled = !enabled;
    }
```

it will just continue the loop even if i unclick my mouse, if i add a break; in there it will just stop the while loop and not continue checking for the condition. Please how do i constantly check for a condition in the while loop?

Edit:
Ok, I’m using Swing for the framework, and what I’m trying to achieve is that when I click my left mouse button, the loop begins and keeps going while the left mouse button is held down but when I lift my finger and the mouse button is released, the loop stops but it doesn’t stop the loop. It just continues the loop even if I unclick my mouse.

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: State your GUI framework. Swing, JavaFX, SWT, etc.

Comment: I believe the approach is wrong.  You don't need to loop and continuously check the mouse state. You get an event on mouseDown and another on mouseUp.  On mouseDown, start whatever process you want in a new thread and loop there as long as mouseUp hasn't arrived.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you can't start an infinite loop here since it will cause a deadlock as soon as the first event occurs. You just need to wait for the function to be called, then update the state accordingly. You can then read and act on the state elsewhere in your program. Since events are in a separate thread than the rest of your program, you can create your loop in the main thread or spawn a new thread.

As a side note, you don't need to check for an exception here. A `MouseEvent` just stores information about an event. After being created it is created it wont be changed.

```java
static boolean enabled = false;

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // Ignore events if they are not for the button we care about
    if (e.getButton() == 1) {
        enabled = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getButton() == 1) {
        enabled = false;
    }
}

// In some other thread (such as the one which created the JPanel)
while (true) {
    if (enabled) {
        System.out.println("registered click");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: i put the loop on a different thread in the class and it hasnt helped, its something with the loop, it isnt checking to see if my mouse is clicked down and just starts the loop when i click down my mouse and not hold. Therefore it doesn't stop the loop when I lift up my leftclick.

Comment: @HH_Captain The principle of Locke is right: `mousePressed` signals start of the loop, `mouseReleased` signal end of the loop. This can be done with a thread and some java.util.concurrent things.

Comment: @JoopEggen running the loop from another thread doesnt change anything...its just the same thing if you put it in the mousePressed or outside

Comment: Call at the three code places a System.out.println, And `volatile boolean pressed = false:` (`static` would global and `volatile` ensures that always an up-to-date value is used in every thread).